# Remove duplicate anchors with the same text value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

How to remove anchors with the exactly same text or content?

```
links = []
$('a').each(function() {
    links.append([$(this).text, $(this)]);
});

grouped = _.groupBy(links, function(input){return input[0]});

for (var i=0;i<grouped.size;i++){
  if (grouped[i].size > 1){
   grouped[i][0][1].remove()
  }
}
```

Seems really clunky and messy and needs underscore. Is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: my original solution wasn't correct — check the updated version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't delete this answer since it was accepted as correct — but, as Jesse points out in the comments below, it wasn't. So I've developed a correct, simpler solution that still seems simpler than the other answers:

```
// A list of all unique HTML strings in links
var strings = [];

$( 'a' ).each( function recordContents(){
  var $candidate = $( this );
  var text       = $candidate.text();

  // If the link's text isn't already in the `strings` array, 
  // it's the first of its kind: add it to the array and move on.
  if( strings.indexOf( text ) === -1 ){
    strings.push( text );
  }
  // If it is, it's a duplicate: remove it.
  else {
    $candidate.remove();
  }
} );
```

[JSbin demo](http://jsbin.com/UHIsUpem/2/).

---

Original accepted answer, for posterity. This code deletes all links which have duplicates on the page, including the first instance of each.

```
var $a = $( 'a' );

$a.each( function removeDuplicates(){
    var $candidate = $( this );
    var text = $candidate.text();
    $a.filter( function filterForDuplicates(){
        return $( this ).not( $candidate ).text() === text;
    } ).remove();
} );
```

Comment: If there are two links with the text "foo", this will remove BOTH links. This may or may not be the desired effect.   http://jsbin.com/iFUqAguw/3/

Comment: I can't see the source of your jsbin link from my mobile, but the selector chain in the `filterForDuplicates` specifies `.not( $candidate )`, which means that the iterated link being used as a candidate will not be removed — all other links with the same text will be.

Comment: Check it when you get on a desktop. It behaves as I have described.

Comment: @jessegavin you're absolutely right. The problem is that the duplicates are not removed from the `each` loop, so when they are iterated over, their 'original' is removed. In fact, this script will remove all links which are duplicates and leave only uniques intact. I can't solve this now, but edits or alternatives welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Could try something like this which only requires jQuery:

```
var linksHtml=[];
$('a').each(function() {
    var html=$(this).html();
   if( $.inArray( html, linksHtml) >-1){
      $(this).remove()
   }else{
      linksHtml.push(html);
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SB9uB/)**</kbd>

Caveat is the html will have to be 100% identical...space for space, letter for letter. But that wouldn't be any different than code you currently have

Answer (score 0):

just add it to the first child or any n child you want, not to every

```
links = []
$('.anchor a:first-child').each(function() {
    links.append([$(this).text, $(this)]);
});

grouped = _.groupBy(links, function(input){return input[0]});

for (var i=0;i<grouped.size;i++){
  if (grouped[i].size > 1){
   grouped[i][0][1].remove()
  }
}
```

make sure to wrap it in div with a class anchor